# Append TR AND change focus to new tr input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I am creating a form with a table that will be used with a barcode scanner.  The table row will start with one row and each time the scanner is used, first a new row would be created and then secondly the focus would drop to a specific input of the newly created row. (basically skipping past the other inputs that existed on the starting row).

I found a similar topic and got this far, but I can't get both creating the new row as well as moving to the new row to work together beyond one extra row.  I can use delegation but then that breaks moving focus to the next row's input...

```
<table id="table1">
 <tr>
   <td><input class="bcode" type="text" name="S1" autofocus/></td>
   <td><input class="b" type="text" name="S2" /></td>
   <td><input class="c" type="text" name="S3" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>

$('#table1').find('.bcode').keypress(function(e){ 
   if ( e.which == 13 ){
    $('<tr><td><input class="bcode" type="text" name="S1" /></td><td><input class="b" type="text" name="S2" /></td><td><input class="c" type="text" name="S3"/></td></tr>').appendTo('#table1');
    $(this).parent().parent().next('tr').find('.bcode').focus();
    return false; 
   } 
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayenfang/3d4x852p/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For events attached to dynamic DOM elements, you should use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Then:

`$(document).on("keyup", ".bcode",(function(e){ 
     //code
    }));`

to listen to new created `.bcode` elements.

You could restrict which `.bcode` elements with this:

```
$("#table1").on("keyup", ".bcode",(function(e){ 
 //code
}));
```

full example here: https://jsfiddle.net/x17r6nf3/3/

Comment: That's perfect!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.on()` here for attaching the event to the existing table and delegate it to the keypress on input.

```
$('#table1').on('keypress', '.bcode', function(e) {
  if ( e.which == 13 ) // Enter key = keycode 13 
  { 
    $('<tr><td><input class="bcode" type="text" name="S1" /></td><td><input class="b" type="text" name="S2" /></td><td><input class="c" type="text" name="S3" /></td></tr>').appendTo('#table1');
    //console.log($(this).next('.bcode'));
    $(this).parent().parent().next('tr').find('.bcode').focus();
    return false;
  } 
});
```

See the attached fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/pmewsqLn/